# stilliard/pure-ftpd: Allow ftp of other docker container?

Tags: docker, prestashop, pureftpd

I have a docker-compose file created that launches 2 services. 1 is prestashop (an online store) which works and the other is the stilliard/pure-ftpd.

I would like to be able to view the contents of the prestashop volume. Can anyone help ?

Here is my docker-compose.yml file (truncated)

```
services:
  prestashop:
    image: prestashop/prestashop:latest

    networks:
      - web

    volumes:
      - prestashop:/var/www/html

  ftpd-server:
    image: stilliard/pure-ftpd:latest

    ports:
      - "21:21"
      - "20:20"
      - "30000-30009:30000-30009"

    networks:
      - web

    environment:
      PUBLICHOST: 192.168.1.2
      FTP_USER_NAME: "test"
      FTP_USER_PASS: "test"
      FTP_USER_HOME: "/var/www/html"
    restart: on-failure

    volumes:
      - prestashop:/var/www/html

volumes:
  db-data:
  prestashop:
```

I am a little stuck. So when somebody FTPs in, i would like them to be able to view and update the /var/www/html from the prestashop volume

Any ideas what I am doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?